# Access denied for root user when trying to import .sql via command line (Vagrant)

Tags: mysql, ssh, command-line, vagrant

I'm relatively new to working with Vagrant and command line.

I want to import a database via command line (too big for PHPMyAdmin GUI).

I've used:

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < db_name.sql
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am using the same username and password I use to access PHPMyAdmin via http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ but it just doesnt work in the command line.

Would anyone know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be two things:

1: I was meant to put a password after -p (even though it was prompting me for it after using the above)

2: I shouldnt have been using spaces after -p and -u.

So:

```
mysql -uroot -pPassword123 db_name < ./db_file.sql
```